# Transferring files using ssh on terminal

Tags: terminal, mac, scp

I am trying to transfer a file to Computer A (my computer) from Computer B (the remote computer). I have looked through different threads, but nothing is working. First, I log onto Computer B using ssh which works fine. My code for the file transfer is

```
scp userB@hostB:~/Desktop/(file_name) ~/Desktop/
```

when I plug this in, it asks for Computer Bs password, which I enter. Then I get the error

`scp: /Users/userB/Desktop/(file_name) : No such file or directory`

I know that the file is there, however. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See Scott's answer below.  Use the full path instead of the aliased path.  Also, you should be doing this from Computer A, *not* ssh-ing into Computer B first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried, while logged on to Computer A :

```
scp (Computer B user)@(Computer B address):/Users/(Computer B user)/Desktop/(file_name) ~/Desktop/
```

It's more explicit than using ~, which may not behave as you might want it to on the remote machine - although it will be fine for local file specifications.

Comment: See my comment above re:  location where he is issuing the command.  He is logging into B and trying to copy a file from B/Desktop to B/Desktop.

Comment: Yeah, the whole thing was confusing ...

Comment: Agree - I had to edit his usernames and hosts to make it easier to understand.  Just upvoted.

Comment: I have clarified my answer a little